# Geo location not working with subdomain

Tags: geolocation, subdomain

i have geo location set to state level so when someone visits it will say "Hello California Visitor. when i use mydomain.com/subdomain it works fine but when i go to subdomain.mydomain.com it does not work properly. Any suggestions?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You'll get better responses if you edit your question to give more detail about what technologies you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out http://github.com/codejoust/session.js/

It looks like you have an issue with the path or a cookie that's including the GeoIP code.